# split a fasta file in a dataframe into columns 4 and rename them , in R

Tags: r, dataframe, file, fasta

//#I have a fASTA file that I want to put in a table with 4 columns

#code
install.packages("seqinr")

```
library("seqinr")
dnaseq<- read.fasta(file = "C:/Users/user/Downloads/my.fasta") 
rows = 4:nrow(dnaseq)
dff<-data.frame(ID = gsub(">","",as.character(dnaseq[rows %% 4==3,3])),names= dnaseq[rows %% 4==2,3],specie= dnaseq[rows %% 4==1,3], sequences = dnaseq[rows %% 4==0,3])
```

#rslt
View(dff)
No data available in table

#i tried too
library(phylotools)
fasta.df = read.fasta("C:/Users/user/Downloads/my.fasta",names=['ID','names','specie','sequence'])
#result

> fasta.df = read.fasta("C:/Users/user/Downloads/my.fasta",names=['ID','names','specie','sequence'])
> Error: unexpected '[' in "fasta.df = read.fasta("C:/Users/user/Downloads/my.fasta",names=["

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have downloaded your fasta file from [gencode](https://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/gencode/Gencode_human/release_36/gencode.v36.transcripts.fa.gz)

Fasta file looks like this

```
>ENST00000456328.2|ENSG00000223972.5|OTTHUMG00000000961|OTTHUMT00000362751.1|DDX11L1-202|DDX11L1|1657|processed_transcript|
GTTAACTTGCCGTCAGCCTTTTCTTTGACCTCTTCTTTCTGTTCATGTGTATTTGCTGTC
>ENST00000450305.2|ENSG00000223972.5|OTTHUMG00000000961|OTTHUMT00000002844.1|DDX11L1-201|DDX11L1|632|transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene|
GTGTCTGACTTCCAGCAACTGCTGGCCTGTGCCAGGGTGCAAGCTGAGTTGGAGGAAAGA
.
.
```

Load required packages

```
#install.packages("seqinr")
library(seqinr)
#install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)
```

First we read the fasta file into R

```
gencode_fasta <- read.fasta(file = "Path/to/my/fasta/file.fa" )
```

extracting the header information into a data frame

```
header_df=as.data.frame(names(gencode_fasta))
```

changing the column name to target_id

```
names(header_df)=c("target_id")
```

splitting the header information into multiple columns

```
header_df=separate(header_df, col=target_id, into=c("transcript","ens_gene","OG","OT","c5","ext_gene","num","type","unknown"), sep="\\|", remove = FALSE)
```

- If your header had less information, change into=c(.....)
- If your separater is not "|", change accordingly

To select only the required columns

```
my_gene_df=header_df[,c("ext_gene","ens_gene","target_id")]
```